# The question is on balancing parentheses. I'm doing it using stack. It doesn't works on only one test case i.e ')'. Else it is working fine

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stack

```
    bool areBracketsBalanced(char exp[]) {
  int len = strlen(exp);
  stack<char> s;
  for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
    char ch = exp[i];
    if(ch=='(' || ch=='[' || ch=='{'){
      s.push(ch);
    }
    else if(!s.empty() && ch==')'){
      if(s.top()=='('){
        s.pop();
      }
      else if(s.top()!='('){
        continue;
      }
    }
    else if(!s.empty() && ch==']'){
      if(s.top()=='['){
        s.pop();
      }
      else if(s.top()!='['){
        continue;
      }
    }
    else if(!s.empty() && ch=='}'){
      if(s.top()=='{'){
        s.pop();
      }
      else if(s.top()!='{'){
        continue;
      }
    }
    
    else{
      continue;
    }
  }
  if(s.empty()){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The question is on balancing parentheses. I'm doing it using stack. It doesn't works on only one test case i.e ')'. Else it is working fine. Please suggest me a change that will work for the test case because i can't figure it out.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good problem description. Please describe the exact input, expected behaviour and actual behaviour. Also the code is incomplete. Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Finally, please note that C and C++ are different languages - I have removed the C tag as it appears to be C++ code.

Comment: You simply ignore mismatched brackets or closing brackets without an opening bracket. Furthermore why use `1` and `0` instead of `true`/ `false`. Furthermore all these `continue;` statements are unnecessary; You don't have to explicitly mention that you want to continue with the next loop iteration, if there is not statement on the execution path for the current loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

So, there is basically a design problem with closing brackets. If you have more closing brackets than opening brackets, your approach will not work.

The reason is that you basically detect the problem, but do not indicate it.

There are three `continue` statements. Those should be modified, because in that `else` parts, it is clear that we have an imbalance.

But beside this problem, there are many other issues that should be improved.

I added comments in you original code.

```
// All variables should always be initialized
#include <stack>     
#include <cstring>     // You should basically not use C-Style headers and functions

using namespace std;   // You should never open the full std namespace. Please use always fully qualified names in it


bool areBracketsBalanced(char exp[]) {  // You should not use C-Style strings something decaying to pointers
    int len = strlen(exp);        // You shold not use C-Style strings and functions. This can be made const
    stack<char> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {    // With C++Strings, you may use the range based for loop
        char ch = exp[i];   // Meaninful variable names should be used. ch can be made const.

        // You do not consider the case when you get a closing bracket and the stack is empty or the wrong element is on the stack
        if (ch == '(' || ch == '[' || ch == '{') {
            s.push(ch);
        }
        else if (!s.empty() && ch == ')') {
            if (s.top() == '(') {
                s.pop();
            }
            else if (s.top() != '(') {
                continue;            // You should not use continue in this case. Continue is nearly like a goto. 
                                    // And it is often an indicator for a bad design on SWE.2 level
            }

        }
        else if (!s.empty() && ch == ']') {  // Somehow repeating. May be redesigned and refactored.
            if (s.top() == '[') {
                s.pop();
            }
            else if (s.top() != '[') {
                continue;    // See above
            }
        }
        else if (!s.empty() && ch == '}') {
            if (s.top() == '{') {
                s.pop();
            }
            else if (s.top() != '{') {
                continue;     // See above
            }
        }

        else {
            continue;  // And again.
        }
    }
    if (s.empty()) {
        return 1;    // A function should always have onle one entry and exit point. So, please no multiple returns.
    }
    else {
        return 0;    // C++ has the constants true and false, which should be used for the return value.
    }
}

int main() {
    char test[] = "[{}}]";
    return areBracketsBalanced(test);
}
```

---

So, lets start to refactor your code.

We will add comments and meaningful names and fix the problem. But still not good.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>     
#include <cstring>     

using namespace std;   


bool bracketsAreBalanced(char *stringToCheck) { 

    // We want to itearte over all characters in the C-String
    // We expect a 0-terminated C-String here
    const size_t lengthOfStringToCheck{ strlen(stringToCheck) };

    // We use a stack for the openining brackets to have a change to do the balancing
    stack<char> bracketStack{};

    // We will use an indicator, if the result is so far OK
    // We initially assume that the result is OK and the brackets are balanced
    bool balanceIsOK{ true };

    // Now, iterate over all characters in the input string.
    // Additionally, if we found an imbalance then we terminate the loop immediately
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lengthOfStringToCheck && balanceIsOK; i++) {

        const char ch = stringToCheck[i];   

        // If there is a closing bracket and not opening bracket on the stack, the something is wrong
        // In this case we have more closing then opening brackets
        if ((ch == ')' || ch == ']' || ch == '}') && bracketStack.empty()) {
            balanceIsOK = false;
        }
        // Check for an opening bracket and push it on the stack
        else if (ch == '(' || ch == '[' || ch == '{') {
            bracketStack.push(ch);
        }
        // We are here, becuase we did not see an opening bracket.
        // Now check all closing bracket types, and if their corresponding opening part is there
        else if (!bracketStack.empty() && ch == ')') {
            if (bracketStack.top() == '(') {
                bracketStack.pop();
            }
            else if (bracketStack.top() != '(') {
                balanceIsOK = false;;
            }                        
        }
        else if (!bracketStack.empty() && ch == ']') {
            if (bracketStack.top() == '[') {
                bracketStack.pop();
            }
            else if (bracketStack.top() != '[') {
                balanceIsOK = false;;
            }
        }
        else if (!bracketStack.empty() && ch == '}') {
            if (bracketStack.top() == '{') {
                bracketStack.pop();
            }
            else if (bracketStack.top() != '{') {
                balanceIsOK = false;;
            }
        }
    }
    // If there are still brackets pn the stack, then we have an imbalance
    if (!bracketStack.empty())
        balanceIsOK = false;

    return balanceIsOK;    
}

int main() {
    char test[] = "aa[aa{aa{aa}a}a}aa]aa";

    if (bracketsAreBalanced(test)) {
        cout << "Balanced\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Not Balanced\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

In c++ we can take advantage of more available and ready to use functionality.

We need to model somehow matching pairs. And this we can do with many possible solutions, for example with a `std::unordred_map`.

Then we can iterate over it and compare with the pair parts.

See one possible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

using Pairs = std::unordered_map<char, char>;
using BracketsSeen = std::stack<char>;

const Pairs pairs{ {'(',')'},{'[',']'},{'{','}'} };


bool bracketsAreBalanced(std::string& stringToCheck) {

    // Here we store all bopening brackets that we saw before
    BracketsSeen bracketsSeen{};

    // Resulting function value. We first assume that everthing is OK
    bool balanceIsOK{ true };

    // Go through all characters in the string
    for (const char c : stringToCheck) {

        // And now check for each existing pair of brackets
        for (const auto& [openingBracket, closingBracket] : pairs) {

            // Push all opening bracktes onto the stack
            if (c == openingBracket)
                bracketsSeen.push(c);

            // If we have a closing bracket, then check, if we have the matching opening bracket
            else if (c == closingBracket) {
                if (bracketsSeen.empty() or bracketsSeen.top() != openingBracket) {
                    balanceIsOK = false;   break;
                }
                else
                    bracketsSeen.pop(); // Match found. Remove from the stack
            }
        }
        // Unfortunately in C++17 there is no other way. So stop, if result is known.
        if (not balanceIsOK) break;
    }
    return balanceIsOK;
}
int main() {
    std::string test{ "aa[aa{aa{aa}aa}aa]aa" };

    if (bracketsAreBalanced(test)) {
        std::cout << "Balanced\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not Balanced\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please see